# Check for an added association on 'create' and 'update' - Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to use an AR callback (after_save) to check, if an association was added on the latest 'update' or 'create'. However, I can't seem to find the correct way to do it.

```
class Submission < ActiveRecord
  has_many :notes, inverse_of: :submission, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :notes, :reject_if => proc { |attributes| attributes['message'].blank? }, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Here is my after_save

```
after_save :build_conversation
```

in that method I want to see, if a new note table was added on update or create...

```
def build_conversation
  if self.notes.any?
   binding.pry
  end
end
```

This logic does not make sense, because if notes can exist, which is fine. Nevertheless, I only want to enter this block, if there is a new note added on update or create...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this post](https://jasoncharnes.com/changed-attributes-rails/). Basically, you add `include ActiveModel::Dirty` in the model, then in the `after_change` callback you check `if_notes_changed`. This method is defined using `method_missing` so for example if you have a `name` column you can use `if_name_changed` and so on. If you need to compare the old vs new values, you can use [previous_changes](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Dirty/previous_changes).

Alternatively, you can use `around_save` like so:

```
around_save :build_conversation

def build_conversation
  old_notes = notes.to_a # the self in self.notes is unnecessary
  yield # important - runs the save
  new_notes = notes.to_a
  # binding.pry
end
```